# Spring Boot doesn't seem to see my web security config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

This is my first time with a Spring Boot secured REST app. I've added spring-boot-starter-security to my classpath, and I understand that automatically secures all URLs. But at this point in my development, I'm not ready to do that, so I added an antMatcher to ALLOW all URLs. But no matter what I put in my WebSecurityConfig, I still get an the error message:

```
Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Below is my WebSecurityConfig in full. Is there something else I need to do for Spring to pick this up? How can verify if it's being used at all? Many thanks!

```
package com.company.jwt.security;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

import com.company.jwt.UserUtils;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
    authBuilder.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
}

@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    UserUtils.getUsers()
        .forEach(e -> props.put(e.getUsername(), e.getPassword() + "," +
                e.getAuthorities() + ", enabled"));
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(props);
}
}
```

Comment: Try removing @EnableWebSecurity

Comment: But I want the infrastructure to be there. I don't want to disable it to fix my problem.

Comment: Spring boot will switch off the auto configuration if you add annotation. See the link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html

Comment: Commenting out EnableWebSecurity didn't do anything.

Comment: Also try adding  @Autowired to second config method...

Comment: @user1660256 I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with the config you shared.  If possible, can you share a link to a minimal example project on GitHub?  That would make troubleshooting easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of URL are you trying to access there? A rest controller that you created?

There may be something overriding the permission of your URLs.

I ran the code bellow with no problem (SpringBoot 1.5.2).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}


$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/foo
foo
```

Comment: I'm trying to access urls that were already existing in the application before I added the Spring security. Yes, they are in a REST controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only difference between our implementations is that you Autowired the AuthenticationManagerBuilder. Mine still won't work. So I tried a different tack - I told the config to allow the URL "/customer" access, and still, no luck. As I look at the debug while my test is starting up, I don't even so my WebSecurityConfig being loaded.